# How to strip tags context-dependent?

Tags: xslt

Suppose I have a source example document like this:

```
<html>
  <b><i><u>TestBIU</u></i></b>
  <i><b><u>TestIBU</u></b></i>
  <i><u><b>TestIUB</b></u></i>
  <b><u><i>TestBUI</i></u></b>
  <u><i><b>TestUIB</b></i></u>
  <u><b><i>TestUBI</i></b></u>
  <u>TestU</u>
  <i>TestI</i>
  <b>TestB</b>
  <u><b>TestUB</b></u>
</html>
```

I need a XSLT-Template that produces this:

```
<html>
  <b><i>TestBIU</i></b>
  <i><b>TestIBU</b></i>
  <i><b>TestIUB</b></i>
  <b><i>TestBUI</i></b>
  <i><b>TestUIB</b></i>
  <b><i>TestUBI</i></b>
  <u>TestU</u>
  <i>TestI</i>
  <b>TestB</b>
  <b>TestUB</b>
</html>
```

So, it should remove the underline tag when it occurs in combination with italic and/or bold tags. When only underlined, it should remain.
Any ideas how to solve this particular problem?

Here is my attempt, but if fails for TestUIB and TestUBI:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="b/u">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="i/u">    
      <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="u/i">
  <i><xsl:apply-templates /></i>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="u/b">
    <b><xsl:apply-templates /></b>
</xsl:template>    
<xsl:template match="b | u | i">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* | text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Is it even possible to match by contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="u[ancestor::b | ancestor::i | descendant::b | descendant::i]">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It produces the following output to your sample:

```
<html>
    <b><i>TestBIU</i></b>
    <i><b>TestIBU</b></i>
    <i><b>TestIUB</b></i>
    <b><i>TestBUI</i></b>
    <i><b>TestUIB</b></i>
    <b><i>TestUBI</i></b>
    <u>TestU</u>
    <i>TestI</i>
    <b>TestB</b>
    <b>TestUB</b>
</html>
```

**Description**: In my solution I'm using [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) that copies everything node by node and attribute by attribute. The second template intercepts all `<u>` HTML tags that have `<i>` or `<b>` amongst their ancestors or descendants. When such situation occurs, we do not copy the tag, but only invoke apply-templates which will take care of its children.

Comment: Is there a semantic difference between the proposed solution of Lukasz and Martin? Both seem to work.

Comment: There is one difference, I used `u[b] | u[i]` for the cases where the `u` element contains either `b` or `i` as a child, which suffices for the sample data you presented. Lukasz goes further with `u[descendant::b | descendant::i]` as it also assumes `b` or `i` could occur as descendants (e.g. as in `<u><span><i>...</i></span></u>`) and that you want to strip the `u` to in that case too.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, Lukasz' solution is more suited to my needs. Thank you both for your answers, it helped a lot. I voted both answers.

Comment: this is version="1.0" solution as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b//u | i//u | u[b] | u[i]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

suffices.